# Validating Form Before Submitting (Linking Checkbox with Dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

If I could have someone help me out, that would be great. I have come to the conclusion that I am not very good at writing validation js. It's quite messy and I can't get parts of it to work the way I need to.

Here is the code I have on my form page:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/form.pl" method="post" name="pledgeform" onSubmit="return validate(this)" id="submitform">

<input type="checkbox" name="m_class" value="Presentation 1">
    <select name="Presentation 1_Priority" id="morn_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="m_class" value="Presentation 2">
    <select name="Presentation 2_Priority" id="morn_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="m_class" value="Presentation 3">
    <select name="Presentation 3_Priority" id="morn_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="m_class" value="Presentation 4">
    <select name="Presentation 4_Priority" id="morn_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="m_class" value="Presentation 5">
    <select name="Presentation 5_Priority" id="morn_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>


<input type="checkbox" name="a_class" value="Presentation 1">
    <select name="Presentation 1_Priority" id="noon_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="a_class" value="Presentation 2">
    <select name="Presentation 2_Priority" id="noon_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="a_class" value="Presentation 3">
    <select name="Presentation 3_Priority" id="noon_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="a_class" value="Presentation 4">
    <select name="Presentation 4_Priority" id="noon_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" name="a_class" value="Presentation 5">
    <select name="Presentation 5_Priority" id="noon_prty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    First Name:<input maxlength="50" name="First_Name" size="32" type="text">
    Last Name:<input maxlength="50" name="Last_Name" size="32" type="text">
    Address: <input maxlength="50" name="Address" size="32" type="text"></p>
    Phone:<input maxlength="15" name="Phone" size="32" type="text"></p>
    Fax:<input maxlength="15" name="Fax" size="32" type="text"></p>
    E-mail:<input maxlength="50" name="Email" size="32" type="text"></p>
    Comments:
    <textarea cols="55" name="comments" rows="10" wrap="physical"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp; <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
</form>
```

It's more so validating the top portion that I'm having trouble with rather than the fields that they fill out. What I need is before the form is sent, it needs to check to make sure that at least 3 morning classes are selected and 3 afternoon classes are selected and if the box is checked, the associated priority list needs to be filled out so we can determine what order they prefer. (I also need to limit it so that no more than 3 can be checked in each section). If anyone has any ideas on how I could do that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Check [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: `id`s MUST be unique. Every `<select>` on your page has the same ID -  try using `class` instead.